# Wanted but not invoked: There were zero interactions with this mock

Tags: powermockito

I am stuck with this issue for the whole day. Tried many resources and debug features but no luck.

Can you guys please help me.

```
public class Data{

    DataDriver dataDriver; // DataDriver is a different class which I have injected.
    Connector connector; // Connector is a different class which I am injecting in Data class.

    // Constructor and Setter methods

    public void read(){
            CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
            Hashmap<String, String> credentials = dataDriver.run(new Date());
            HttpGet get = connector.execute(client,credentials);
    }
}
```

For my test class, I am using Powermockito, as `HttClients.createDefault()` is a static method.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/XXX.xml" })
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class DataTest {

    Data mockeddata;

    @Mock
    Connector mockedconnector;

    @Mock
    DataDriver mockeddataDriver;

    @Mock
    CloseableHttpClient mockedClient;

    @Before
    public void Setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(Data.class);
        mockeddata =new Data();
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(HttpClients.class);
        mockedData.setConnector(mockedconnector);
        mockedData.setDataDriver(mockedDataDriver);
    }

    @Test
    @PrepareForTest({ HttpClients.class })
    public void testRead(){
        HashMap<String, String> credentials = new HashMap<String, String>();    
        PowerMockito.when(HttpClients.createDefault()).thenReturn(mockedClient);
        PowerMockito.when(mockeddataDriver.run(newDate())).thenReturn(credentials);
        PowerMockito.when(mockedconnector.execute(mockedClient,credentials)).thenReturn(new HttpGet());
        verify(mockedconnector, atLeastOnce()).execute(mockedClient, credentials);
    }
}
```

It says zero interactions with the connector mock. Its not complaining on the dataDriver mock. I tried debugging and was able to see both my mock objects in the Data class. But its not going into the *execute* funtion of the Connector.

Any advise on what I am doing wrong?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when you verify the parameters Mockito is creating different object references (different objects)...
Try verifying with `eq()` method to make sure that the parameters you expect are the same as `when` that you have defined before.

`verify(mockedconnector,atLeastOnce()).execute(eq(mockedClient),eq(credentials));`

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your `read` method from your test class.